# Problem with focus transfer on HTML select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form made up of a number rows similar to the following HTML -

```
<div style="display: table-row">
     <div style="display: table-cell">
          <label for="Region">Region</label>
     </div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">
           <select  id="Region" name="Region">
               <option value="">Please Select</option>
               <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
               <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
               <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
           </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have an HoverOut event that fires when the user moves their mouse cursor out of the outer most  that removes focus form the input field in the row.  I have some styling that I apply to the row when the row has focus and I remove it when mouse is not over  My problem is with Select statements and IE7/8.

If FF5, if I'm using the mouse to select an entry from the select drop down, everything works as expected.  However, with IE7/8, what happens is that the outer row receives the mouseout event (firing hover-out) as soon as the mouse cursor leaves the area of the div tag, while I'm attempt to select an entry from the drop down.  If I leave the mouse over the div and use the cursor keys to navigate the list, it works fine.

My question is there a way to prevent the mouseout event from being passed to the outer row while I'm still selecting a value from the select list.

You can see working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/9JXfk/9/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

this will stop event propagation.